# Change text on hover with the href value, placeholder on MouseOut, for several elements?

Tags: jquery

I was hoping you could help with this. The arrows are the placeholder text. I just want the text to change on hover with the section you should go to and to go back to the arrow on mouseOut. The problem i have here is that it's assigning the same href value to all the `<a>`.
There's probably 10 better ways to write this. Suggestions?
Oh, the HTML doesn't render the arrows, just the plain ↑ text....¿?

```
$('.nav-sections')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        var NextSection = "&darr;" // downwards arrow
        var PrevSection = "&uarr;" // upwards arrow
        var targetFull = $(this).find("a").attr("href").split("#")
        var targetClean = targetFull[1]
        $(this).find("a").text(targetClean)
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find("a").text("&darr;");
        $(this).find("a:first-child").text("&uarr;");
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of HTML that the code is acting on?

Comment: thanks for your responses! I sort it out in a different way given that the href value wasn't always what i wanted to be rendered in the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one first. change the text() function to html(), this will solve your test formatting in plain text.

Its difficult to help without a snippet of the html code as mentioned but i would assume:
assuming this is your code:

```
<ul class=".nav-sections">
    <li><a href="jamie">Jamie</a><a href="jamie" class="secondlink">Jamie 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="hutber">hutber</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would just change the jquery selector to

```
$('.nav-sections a')
```

then the code to:

```
$('.nav-sections li a:first-child')
.mouseenter(function(){
     var NextSection = "&darr;" // downwards arrow
    var PrevSection = "&uarr;" // upwards arrow
    var targetFull = $(this).attr("href").split("#")
    var targetClean = targetFull[1]
    $(this).html(targetClean)
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).html("&darr;");
    $(this).find("a.secondlink").html("&uarr;");
});
```

So this way you're not having to find anything and you can be more specific with what you want.

Still not quite sure if this is what you're after

Comment: thanks for your responses! I sort it out in a different way given that the href value wasn't always what i wanted to be rendered in the a tag.